# Finding an item in a List<> using C#

Tags: c#, .net

I have a list which contains a collection of objects.

How can I search for an item in this list where `object.Property == myValue`?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

What is wrong with [List.Find](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.find) ??

I think we need more information on what you've done, and why it fails, before we can provide truly helpful answers.

Comment: If you are using .NET 3.0 or later, you should favor the LINQ way because LINQ works on any IEnumerable and IEnumerable<T>. The Find-Method is specific for List<T> and cannot help you once you have to deal with different collections.

Comment: To short answer, no code sample... Answer below is much better.

Comment: I know I am kinda late to the party, but this answer is very much useless for someone coming to find information. It does not explain what List.Find can do and how to use it. Contrast to Drew Noakes explanation, that goes into deeper explanation how to use it, which actually gives a proper answer to the question of "how to find an item in a list". This answer is nothign more than a link to a function, with zero explanation WHY one should use the function in the link.

Answer (score 167):

You have a few options:

1. Using [Enumerable.Where](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.where) and [Enumerable.FirstOrDefault](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.firstordefault):

   ```
    list.Where(i => i.Property == value).FirstOrDefault();       // C# 3.0+
   ```
2. Using [Enumerable.FirstOrDefault](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.firstordefault) on its own:

   ```
    list.FirstOrDefault(i => i.Property == value);               // C# 3.0+
   ```
3. Using [List.Find](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.find):

   ```
    list.Find(i => i.Property == value);                         // C# 3.0+

    list.Find(delegate(Item i) { return i.Property == value; }); // C# 2.0+
   ```

All of these options return `default(T)` (`null` for reference types) if no match is found.

As mentioned in the comments below, you should use the appropriate form of comparison for your scenario:

- `==` for simple value types or where use of operator overloads are desired
- `object.Equals(a, b)` for most scenarios where the type is unknown or comparison has potentially been overridden
- `string.Equals(a, b, StringComparison)` for comparing strings
- `object.ReferenceEquals(a, b)` for identity comparisons, which are usually the fastest

Comment: Forgot to mention I'm using .net v2

Comment: @Peter -- haha, nice one.  It's early here and the compiler in my brain is off duty :)

Comment: You should compare using `Equals` unless you know `==` is valid for the particular type you're comparing. `==` will most often compare reference identity, which has a good chance of not having desirable semantics.

Comment: I generally use `object.Equals(a,b)` when I don't know the type (most times you're looking in a list, you do know the type) as this takes type-specific comparison into account and deals neatly with nulls, though the exception to this rule is for string comparisons, for which the programmer should indicate whether it's an ordinal or culture-sensitive comparison (via `string.Equals(a,b,StringComparison)`.

Comment: I didn't really mean situations where you actually don't know the type (indeed `object.Equals` is a good choice there). My intent was more to say that by default you should use `Equals`, and only if you are *certain* `==` is correct (e.g. immutable types that overload it, or reference types that don't overload it but for which you want reference equality) should you consider using it.

Comment: @Joren - Agreed. I think we're both on the same page :)

Answer (score 9):

```
var myItem = myList.Find(item => item.property == "something");
```

Answer (score 2):

```
item = objects.Find(obj => obj.property==myValue);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
list.FirstOrDefault(i => i.property == someValue);
```

This is based on Drew's answer above, but a little more succinct.

Answer (score 0):

For .NET 2.0:

```
list.Find(delegate(Item i) { return i.Property == someValue; });
```